# How do I restart Jetty Server in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

Jetty server was running fine. I made little changes in my code and now I want to restart it. With Tomcat it was easy because you have GUI interface to restart it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can accomplish this, we have a page in the docs on Hot Deployment: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/hot-deployment.html

Basically if you are using a webapp you can set it up to restart by touching a deployment descriptor or through jmx.